# Como formatar data Apr 17 1995 12:00:00:000AM para 1995-04-17 em java script?

Tags: javascript

Estou puxando uma data direto do SQLServer, porém esta me retornando nesse formato Apr 17 1995 12:00:00:000AM é possível criar uma função que me retorne esse formato 1995-17-04 com js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cria uma função para formatar a data.
Lidar com datas no JavaScript pode ser um pouco chato, então você pode fazer assim:

```js
function formatDate(sqlDate) {
  var date = new Date(sqlDate.substring(0, 11)),
      year = date.getFullYear(),
      month = String(date.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'),
      day = String(date.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');

  return year + '-' + month + '-' + day;
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Leonardo!